# Recursion function returns wrong value

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have wrote the following code for generating sum of number e-g if I enter 10 it will generate it's sum like 10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1+0 output : 55 which works fine.

```
public int GenerateSum(int num)
    {
        if (num <=0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int temp = num + GenerateSum(num - 1);
        return temp;
    }
```

Now I have changed this code to generate the difference e-g if I enter a number say 10 it will generate it's difference like 10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0 output : -35

```
public int GenerateDifference(int num)
    {
        if (num <= 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        int temp = num - GenerateDifference(num - 1);
        return temp;
    }
```

Now when I run the GenerateDifference(10) it returns me output 5. For GenerateDifference(100) it gives me output 50 which is also wrong. If it's working for sum it should work for difference also (If I am wrong please correct me). Any help or guidance on that.?

Comment: Check the desired precedence/order of the operations. You are computing 10-(9-(8-(7-(6-(5-(4-(3-(2-(1-0))))))))).

Comment: 10-(9-(8-(7-(6-(5-(4-(3-(2-(1-0))))))))) != 10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0

Comment: Well, "the difference between all numbers from 0 to n" just doesn't make sense as "the sum of all numbers from 0 to n" does.

Comment: @MOehm yes you are right it doesn't. I am combining little pieces together to built something meaningful and in which the difference part is helpful that's why I came across such situation and asked for help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code gives 5 because when you use recursion to generate `10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0`, what recursion ends up doing is

```
10 - ( 9 - ( 8 - ( 7 - ( 6 - ( 5 - ( 4 - ( 3 - ( 2 - ( 1 - 0) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

solve the above equation, you would get `5` as answer

since you need the solution of `10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0` you can simplify that to `10 - ( 9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1+0 )`. Then to get the answer using recursion you will need something like this

```
public int GenerateDifference(int num)
{
    if (num <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int temp = num - GenerateSum(num - 1);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I didn't knew that I have to evaluate it using parenthesis. Thanks a lot. can you suggest me some best article from which I can remove my other ambiguities related to recursion.

Comment: @JamalHussain: i gave parentheses just to make it clear what executes first and what is the sequence of execution. you can think of recursion as using stack, which pushes the present function and then calls the next one. In the end, the execution is done from the top of the stack popping every function as it is completed.
read this link. it might help you.
(http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Programming_Concepts/Recursive_Techniques)

Answer (score 1):

You will obtain the value of `10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0` with `10 - GenerateSum(9)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem of sign :

10 - ( 9 - (8 - ( 7-(6-(5-(4-(3-(2-(1-(0))))))))))) = 10 - 9 +8 - 7 + 6 -5 +4 -3 +2 -1 = 5

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public int GenerateDifference(int num)
{
    if (num <= 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int temp = num - GenerateSum(num - 1);
    return temp;
}

public int GenerateSum(int num)
{
    if (num <=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int temp = num + GenerateSum(num - 1);
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example on PHP.

```
function sum($n) {
    if ($n <= 0) return 0; else return $n + sum($n-1);
}

function diff($n) {
    return $n - sum($n - 1);
}
```